# Webview not getting specific content from website

Tags: android

I am encountering a problem where I cannot get specific content from a website.

Here is the website:

http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=CURRENCY%3AUSD&ei=hYbQUcC3LJS80QHnDA

Here is part of my code:

```
public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('gb')    .style.visibility= 'hidden';");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('gb')    .style.display   = 'none'  ;");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('appbar').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('appbar').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('gf-nav').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('gf-nav').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }
    }

private void AddListenerOnButton() {
    spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final WebView webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            String text1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD")) {
                wc.onPageFinished(webView, "http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=CURRENCY%3AUSD&ei=hYbQUcC3LJS80QHnDA");
                wc.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, "http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=CURRENCY%3AUSD&ei=hYbQUcC3LJS80QHnDA");
            }               
        }
```

Instead of getting specific content, webview is returning all of its content.  This:

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('gb')    .style.visibility= 'hidden';");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('gb')    .style.display   = 'none'  ;");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('appbar').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('appbar').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('gf-nav').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
        builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('gf-nav').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }
    }
```

was supposed to only get the information off of google, but it didn't work.  Here is the part of the website I want:

http://oi44.tinypic.com/2ilnhwi.jpg

What is happening here?  What can I do to fix it?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

two problems

1. StringBuilder result was never used
2. "javascript:" prefix schould only be used once in the loadUrl() call.

---

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('gb')    .style.visibility= 'hidden';");
    builder.append("document.getElementById('gb')    .style.display   = 'none'  ;");
    builder.append("document.getElementById('appbar').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
    builder.append("document.getElementById('appbar').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
    builder.append("document.getElementById('gf-nav').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
    builder.append("document.getElementById('gf-nav').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
    view.loadUrl(builder.toString());
}
```